# Remove the <ul> Tag from wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, theme-development, menus, navigation, list

I want to remove the `<ul>` tags from the `wp_nav_menu`. I already found different posts about it here but they don´t seem to work for me. Here is what I did:

First I registered the menu in functions.php:

```
add_action('init', 'register_custom_menu');

function register_custom_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('main-navi', __('Main-Navi'));
}
```

Then I created the menu in the Wordpress backend.

After that I put following code into my `header.php` :

```
<?php $args = array(
    'menu' => 'main-navi',
    'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
    'container' => false );
?>
<?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
```

But the output is still the following:

```
<ul id="menu-main-navi">
    <li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-5">
       <a href="http://fruchtkiste.eu/blog.leitblick-wp">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4">
       <a href="http://fruchtkiste.eu/blog.leitblick-wp/?page_id=2">Leistungen</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's working for me. If there isn't an ul-tag in your template file, it could be that your theme or a plugin filters `wp_nav_menu`. Add `remove_all_filters('wp_nav_menu', 99);` in your `functions.php` to remove any existing filter hook and test again.

Comment: I checked for plugin filters and also tried to add the filter-removal line but it doesn´t seem to work :/ I´ll just keep trying around until someone maybe has THE answer :)

Comment: Okay I´ve made a mistake. I didn´t tell the menu to be displayed in the 'main-navi' but it still doesn´t work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) ); ?>
```

Source http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Removing_the_ul_wrap

Answer (score 0):

Since it didn't work any other way, I used jQuery to unwrap the menu.

I put in `$('li.menu-item').unwrap();` and everything worked fine.